I am developing obd-ii diagnostic tool and format for fault code doesn't match (DTC decoding from mode 03)
I am developing OBD-II diagnostic tool. For fault code or diagnostic trouble code, I am using mode 03. I am also using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs for reference. However, the output I receive from the obd Bluetooth elm 327 device is not in the format given in Wikipedia. For example, I am receiving output as "43010010" which says that output should be P0010, whereas the logic I use with reference to Wikipedia gives output as P0100. Can someone please help me with how to decode the output received from mode 03 to get correct fault code.
I am using Wikipedia link as reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs#Service_03_(no_PID_required)
Is there anything that I am missing here? I am using standard PIDS for now. Will it be sufficient for initial development.
Below is the logic that I am using.
